# Give a function that is in EXPTIME but is not in O(2^n)

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

Give a function that is in EXPTIME but is not in O(2^n).
Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? Are you aware of the time-hierarchy theorem and its proof? Also, your title and question differ, the title being the more reasonable.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the time-hierarchy theorem is, how can this be used to help find examples of problems in EXPTIME but not in O(2^n)? (Excuse my ignorance in the topic).

Comment: The question in the body doesn't make sense. Any problem that has a worst-case time complexity of anything at all _can_ be solved by a deterministic Turing machine: time complexity is _defined_ by solving problems on Turing machines.

Comment: 1. The title asks a different question than the body, so it's not clear what you intend to ask.  Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking, and to make sure the two match.  2. What research have you done?  What are your thoughts?  We want to help you understand concepts, not do exercises for you; for that to work, you need to give it a try yourself and show us what you've tried and what you do understand and what you're stuck on.

Comment: The problem is ill-posed: EXPTIME is a set of problems, $O(2^n)$ is a set of functions. Or do you want a function that is not in $O(2^n)$ but can be computed in exponential time? Somehow I doubt that, and that would be trivial as well.

Comment: Editing the body to just be a copy-paste of the title, with nothing else, is not helpful.  As I explained, please provide some explanation of the research you've done and what your thoughts are and what you've tried.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. We want high-quality questions here, where you've put some thought into the question and time into formulating it carefully, not dashed-off one-liners.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples. You should check the definitions of $EXPTIME$ and $DTIME$ and also the [time-hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).

$EXPTIME = \cup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} DTIME(2^{n^k})$, and by time-hierarchy theorem $DTIME(2^n) \subsetneq DTIME(2^{n^2})$. Now construct a language following the proof of the time-hierarchy theorem that is in $DTIME(2^{n^2})$ and therefore in $EXPTIME$ but not in $DTIME(2^{n})$. This you should be able to do yourself.